# Creating chart using pygal

Tags: python

im new to python and im using pygal to create stacked line chart as it is simple and easy,however is there a way to open the chart like the normal `plt.show()` i don't want to open it on browser. Or is there another simpler way to create line chart?

Comment: you wanna get image export ?

Comment: http://pygal.org/first_steps/